# NotFoundError: [_Derived_]No gradient defined for op: StatefulPartitionedCall on Tensorflow 1.15.0

Tags: tensorflow, nlp

I am running a `tensorflow` model using `BERT` in the embedding layer. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393980/notfounderror-derived-no-gradient-defined-for-op-einsum-on-tensorflow-1-15) similar question with no answer. Honestly I do not understand why the error is occurring, because the model runs fine for another dataset.

When i call `model.fit`

```
  train_history = model.fit(
    train_input, train_labels,
    validation_split=0.2,
    epochs=3,
    batch_size=8
)
```

I get this error:

```
  NotFoundError:  [_Derived_]No gradient defined for op: StatefulPartitionedCall
     [[{{node Func/_4}}]]
     [[PartitionedCall/gradients/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/PartitionedCall/gradients/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/SymbolicGradient]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_28080]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

> Model:

```
    def build_model(bert_layer, max_len=512):
        input_word_ids = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
        input_mask = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_mask")
        segment_ids = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="segment_ids")

        _, sequence_output = bert_layer([input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])
        clf_output = sequence_output[:, 0, :]
        out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(clf_output)
        
        model = Model(inputs=[input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids], outputs=out)
        model.compile(Adam(lr=2e-6), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        
        return model
```

> Loading BERT from Tensorflow hub

```
    %%time
    module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2"
    bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer(module_url, trainable=True)
```

> Loading tokenizer and encoding text

```
    vocab_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy()
    do_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()
    tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file, do_lower_case)

    train_input = bert_encode(train.text.values, tokenizer, max_len=160)
    test_input = bert_encode(test.text.values, tokenizer, max_len=160)
    train_labels = train['label']

    train_labels = to_categorical(np.asarray(train_labels.factorize()[0]))

    type(train_input)
    >> tuple

    type(train_labels)
    >> numpy.ndarray
```

> Run model

```
model = build_model(bert_layer, max_len=160)
model.summary()


 Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_word_ids (InputLayer)     [(None, 160)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_mask (InputLayer)         [(None, 160)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
segment_ids (InputLayer)        [(None, 160)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
keras_layer (KerasLayer)        [(None, 768), (None, 177853441   input_word_ids[0][0]             
                                                                 input_mask[0][0]                 
                                                                 segment_ids[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice (Tens [(None, 768)]        0           keras_layer[0][1]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 8)            6152        tf_op_layer_strided_slice[0][0]  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 177,859,593
Trainable params: 177,859,592
Non-trainable params: 1
__________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because of using an older version of `tf` with `bert`. I missed [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/540) issue which answers the question.